# Sprite Kit - Rotate to face the ground

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift

I made a sprite to stand on the ground, but i would want the sprite to rotate to face the ground, so that it would look like he is crawling on the ground instead.

```
func setUpRunner() {
    let runnerSize = CGSizeMake(15, 40)
    Runner = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: runnerSize)
    Runner.fillColor = SKColor.blackColor()
    Runner.name = self.rName

    Runner.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: runnerSize)
    Runner.physicsBody.dynamic = true
    Runner.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = true
    Runner.physicsBody.allowsRotation = false
    Runner.physicsBody.restitution = 0.0
    Runner.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = rCategory
    Runner.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = groundCategory

    Runner.position = CGPointMake(20, self.frame.height/3)
    self.addChild(Runner)
}

func crouch() {
    Runner.zRotation = 90 //or -90
}
```

But this would make him face either North-East, North-West.

Comment: Just some general advice on the subject - When programming, always assume radians are used instead of degrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the API of SKNode. It says

```
zRotation
The Euler rotation about the z axis (in radians).
```

This means 360 degrees are `2*M_PI` and thus 90 degrees are `M_PI/2`